# replaceAll not working as expected on a String

Tags: java, regex, string

I have this line of code:  `temp5.replaceAll("\\W", "");`

The contents of temp5 at this point are: `[1, 2, 3, 4]`    but the regex doesn't remove anything. And when I do a toCharArray() I end up with this:  `[[, 1, ,,  , 2, ,,  , 3, ,,  , 4, ]]`

Am I not using the regex correctly? I was under the impression that  \W should remove all punctuation and white space.

Note: temp5 is a String

And I just tested using  \w, \W, and various others. Same output for all of them

Comment: yes temp 5 is a string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are immutable. [`replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) returns the string with the changes made, it does not modify `temp5`. So you might do something like this instead:

```
temp5 = temp5.replaceAll("\\W", "");
```

After that, `temp5` will be `"1234"`.

Comment: Oh my god....I am stupid....thanks a bunch (should have read the freaking API  ugh)

Comment: looks like 2day, you will reach 10K :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    String temp5="1, 2, 3, 4";

    temp5=temp5.replaceAll("\\W", "");

    System.out.println(temp5.toCharArray());
```

This will help